# How to split list elements as words when text and integers are present in python?

Tags: python

I have list like below

```
['Hi','What is my commission','Yes',31289,'Are you sure?','Yes','Okay Thanks.I remember the applications submitted were atleast 50','Then how am I only getting paid for 10 contracts?','Okay.','No thanks..']
```

I have to split above list elements as words.
I tried like below

```
newUserList=[word for line in userList for word in line.split()]
```

It is giving `**error: 'int' object has no attribute 'split' **`

How to split elements as words if text and integer values are present in list?

Comment: You can use `str(line).split()`

Comment: Solved.Thank you so much.It is simple.

Comment: or newUserList = [word for line in userList for word in line.split() if type(word) == str]

Comment: @VladimirKolenov your way will miss integers, `str()` looks much more elegant